# python multiprocessing manager.list inside manager.dict

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

The following python code:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
globals = manager.dict()
globals["queue"] = manager.Queue()

#following line fails
globals["queue"].put("Starting")
```

fails with error:

```
  File "<string>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 732, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', <queue.Queue object at 0x7feb68a68ef0>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you are abusing the thread-safe dict by attempting to store non-serializable queue (which is thread-safe on its own). The best way to go about it is to use independent variables to store the collections created with `manager`:

```
d = manager.dict()
q = manager.Queue()
```

then `q.put("Starting")` works. You need to pass it directly to the function or method that is going to be executed in a separate process, e.g.:

```
def f(d,q):
    d['a'] = 1
    q.put('a')

p = Process(target=f, args=(d,q,))
```

`multiprocessing.manager` is supposed to be used as the provider of thread-safe collections that can be reused by threads and processes. The caveat is that objects originating from the `manager` cannot hold other objects that were created using it.

I recommend a read of the [documentation of `multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) which is very friendly and has a lot of good examples to start with.

Comment: Thanks @sophros The issue was that I wanted to pass a whole lot of variables to a process, and I didn't want to have a huge method signature. I thought a more elegant way was to package all the shared state into a global dict and then pass it around to sub-processes. In retrospect it makes sense for python to complain about this because the manager queue has a lot of logic/code attached to it so it is not a simple object that can be serialized and sent to a different process (possibly even on a different machine).

Comment: Even very complex objects are serializable in Python. The ones that are not serializable hold references to things that cannot be guaranteed to not change when unpickled (e.g. a reference to file, mutex, network/database connection, etc.). In this situation it is a mutex, semaphore or reference to the Process (to be verified in the implementation) that cannot be pickled (and it would not make sense to do so).

Comment: The documentation link you have shared doesn't mention anything about Manager being thread or process safe. Please can you tell me your source?

Comment: It is not the Manager that has to be thread-safe, but the variables it allows to create are thread- or process-safe.